# Favicon not showing when I open a document within Laravel app

Tags: laravel, favicon

I have a favicon showing fine on the homepage in my Laravel app, however, for any document i try to open, the favicon disappears.

The favicon is set in app.blade:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://website.test/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

And document is opened using:

```
<a href="/files/13" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

[image]

The new window isnt using the page template and looking in dev tools, there is no favicon. Any ideas what i'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using packages, most of time packages won't extend the blade template from your app.

A fast solution is change your `favicon-16x16.png` name to `favicon.ico`**(must match name)** and put it in your public path, browsers will trying to find `/favicon.ico` when you didn't link the icon.

The other way, suppose you are using some kind of packages to view pdf, it's normally publish itself blade template into views, find the viewer blade and add your link into it.